# Accessing array in MongoDB using EJS

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have this code (user.js):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String,
        //required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    bio: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

}, {timestamps: true});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

What I'm trying to do is that I'm trying to access the username variable in my EJS file, specifically this line (this can be seen at profile.ejs):

```
<span class="username"> <%= user.username %> </span>
```

The purpose of it is to display the recently inputted username into the web page. I already tried <%= user.username %> but it didn't work.

Here's the route:

```
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    res.render('profile');
});
```

profile is the EJS file that should display the username.

This is the Node.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./models/user');
const Post = require('./models/post');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();

// mongoDB
const dbURI = 'mongodb+srv://DeveloperOne:pepper143@the-little-helper.9kzsf.mongodb.net/the-little-helper?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
mongoose.connect(dbURI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then((result) => app.listen(3000))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + 'public/images'));
app.use('/jquery', express.static(__dirname + 'public/jquery'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + 'public/js'));
app.use('/media', express.static(__dirname + 'public/jquery'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/venobox'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/webfonts'));

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/create-post', (req, res) => {

});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});


app.get('/index2', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index2');
});

app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    res.render('profile');
});

app.post('/index2', (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body);
    //console.log(user.username);
    user.save()
    .then((result) => {
        res.redirect('/index2');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
});

app.get('/baking_feed', (req, res) => {
    res.render('baking_feed');
});

app.get('/baking_feed2', (req, res) => {
    res.render('baking_feed2');
});

app.get('/cooking_feed', (req, res) => {
    res.render('cooking_feed');
});

app.get('/cooking_feed2', (req, res) => {
    res.render('cooking_feed2');
});

app.get('/budgeting_feed', (req, res) => {
    res.render('budgeting_feed');
});

app.get('/budgeting_feed2', (req, res) => {
    res.render('budgeting_feed2');
});

app.get('/gardening_feed', (req, res) => {
    res.render('gardening_feed');
});

app.get('/gardening_feed2', (req, res) => {
    res.render('gardening_feed2');
});

app.get('/sewing_feed', (req, res) => {
    res.render('sewing_feed');
});

app.get('/sewing_feed2', (req, res) => {
    res.render('sewing_feed2');
});
```

and the new EJS file (profile.ejs) that needs to display the username (the one with USERNAME HERE):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Profile</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="venobox/venobox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/venobox/venobox.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <label class="homepage"><i class="fab fa-angellist"></i> Company Name</label>
            <ul> 
                <li><a class="active" href="/index2"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="profile-header">
                <div class="profile-img">
                    <img src = "./images/art.jpg" width="200">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info-border">
                <div class="profile-info">
                    <span class="username"> USERNAME HERE </span>
                    <span class="user-desc">Insert bio here</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="profile-option">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="active" id="button" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i> Edit Profile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="main-profile">
                <div class="main-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li onclick="tabs(0)" class="user-posts active"><i class="fas fa-stream"></i>  Posts</li>
                        <li onclick="tabs(1)" class="user-collections"><i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i> Collections</li>
                        <li onclick="tabs(2)" class="user-faves"><i class="fas fa-star"></i> Favorites</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="profile-body">
                    <div class="profile-posts tab">
                        <div class="videos">
                            <div class="video" style="background-image: url(media/reef.jpg);">
                                <a class="venobox" data-autoplay="true" data-vbtype="video" href="https://youtu.be/DV0vpUmugMc"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="video" style="background-image: url(media/reef.jpg);">
                                <a class="venobox" data-autoplay="true" data-vbtype="video" href="https://youtu.be/DV0vpUmugMc"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="video" style="background-image: url(media/reef.jpg);">
                                <a class="venobox" data-autoplay="true" data-vbtype="video" href="https://youtu.be/DV0vpUmugMc"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="video" style="background-image: url(media/reef.jpg);">
                                <a class="venobox" data-autoplay="true" data-vbtype="video" href="https://youtu.be/DV0vpUmugMc"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile-collections tab">Insert collection here</div>
                    <div class="profile-faves tab">Insert faves here</div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="close">+</div>
                <img src = "./images/profile.png" width="200">
                <form action="">
                    <div class="user-details">
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <span class="avatar"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Change Avatar</span>
                            <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <span class="user-name"><i class="far fa-id-card"></i> Username</span>
                            <input type="text" class="modal-input" placeholder="Enter your username" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <span class="email"><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i> Email Address</span>
                            <input type="email" class="modal-input" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <span class="bio"><i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i> Bio</span>
                            <input type="text" class="modal-input" placeholder="Write a short description" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <span class="old-password"><i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i> Old Password</span>
                            <input type="password" class="modal-input" plac eholder="Enter your old password" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <span class="new-password"><i class="fas fa-key"></i> New Password</span>
                            <input type="password" class="modal-input" placeholder="Enter your new password" required>
                        </div>    
                    </div>                   
                    <div class="button">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="./jquery/profile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the flow of the program is this, first, it asks for the user to register (index.ejs) then after that it redirects the user to (index2.ejs) which is the home page for registered users and when the user clicks on the profile page (profile.ejs), it should display their username and other details.

Comment: Can you add the route that you're using to render this page to the question?

Comment: To render a page you should have a get route with res.render

Comment: @MohamedOraby app.get('/index2', (req, res) => { res.render('index2'); }); like this?

Comment: Yes, but you would need to get the user from database using findOne and render it the page, check the answer below for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your get route should look something this

```
app.get('/index2/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
    return res.render('index2', { user })
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(err)
  }
})
```

EDIT: I made some changes to your code, I have added a user list that accesses users and on click redirects to their profile so you can get the idea of how to get user._id from DB

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./models/user');
// const Post = require('./models/post');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path')

const app = express();

// mongoDB
const dbURI = 'mongodb+srv://DeveloperOne:pepper143@the-little-helper.9kzsf.mongodb.net/the-little-helper?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then((result) => app.listen(3000))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/venobox'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/webfonts'));

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/create-post', (req, res) => {

});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});


app.get('/index2', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index2');
});

app.get('/profile/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
  return res.render('profile', { user });
});

app.post('/index2', (req, res) => {
  const user = new User(req.body);
  //console.log(user.username);
  user.save()
    .then((result) => {
      res.redirect('/index2');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
});

app.get('/baking_feed', (req, res) => {
  res.render('baking_feed');
});

app.get('/baking_feed2', (req, res) => {
  res.render('baking_feed2');
});

app.get('/cooking_feed', (req, res) => {
  res.render('cooking_feed');
});

app.get('/cooking_feed2', (req, res) => {
  res.render('cooking_feed2');
});

app.get('/budgeting_feed', (req, res) => {
  res.render('budgeting_feed');
});

app.get('/budgeting_feed2', (req, res) => {
  res.render('budgeting_feed2');
});

app.get('/gardening_feed', (req, res) => {
  res.render('gardening_feed');
});

app.get('/gardening_feed2', (req, res) => {
  res.render('gardening_feed2');
});

app.get('/sewing_feed', (req, res) => {
  res.render('sewing_feed');
});

app.get('/sewing_feed2', (req, res) => {
  res.render('sewing_feed2');
});

app.get('/user-list', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find()
    return res.render('user-list', { users })
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400)
  }
})
```

and in you profile.ejs `<span class="username"><%= user.username %></span>` should work

Comment: This works! But the the EJS file won't read the <%=  %> tag itself. The first < is red and the rest of the text is white.

Comment: Are you sure the the user itself is found? because I can't see an issue with your ejs format try `console.log(user)` if it returns null then make sure your id is correct (the document _id)

Comment: it 100% works, I just tried console log right now and it displayed my inputs in terminal. Maybe <% %> has been taken down already? ugh.

Comment: <%= %> work fine for me, try maybe rendering the user.username somewhere else with h1 tag maybe it's a css issue?

Comment: I'm not sure why but when I run the index2 web page, it displays Cannot read property 'username' of null. But it has a value.

Comment: So when you visit /index2/:id it says that user is undefined and your console.log is logging the user correctly? make sure that your render has the user object `{ user }`

Comment: if the error continues please update the code in the question with the app.get route and the ejs file

Comment: for the "const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })", I have a variable called User that stores the model of the user.js file, const User = require('./models/user');, maybe this might be the problem?

Comment: no, it's actually supposed to be exactly like this, my guess is either you're using wrong id in the params but you said that you got the output in the console or you're missing the `{ user }` in  `return res.render('index2', { user })` if both are correct please update code from your app in the question

Comment: edited my post again! I hope I didn't confuse you.

Comment: Can you edit your `app.get('/profile')` to look like the code in my answer and use the _id mongo id you get when you create the user? To look like `app.get('/profile/:id')`

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I use the mongo id, do I replace the :id with the mongo id? Apologies, our prof didn't teach us anything and i've only been coding html for a month.

Comment: I have edited the answer with a code that would help you understand how to get ._id and route based on query